# 404 error while accessing resource via 443 port

Tags: iis, https

getting a 404 error while trying to access default.aspx via 443 - 443 is not blocked and this is IIS6.1 on a windows 2008 box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 404 means the URL you are requesting cannot be found on the server. Is it valid according to your web server logs? Are you sure you have the folder path and file name correct?

Maybe your server has not been configured to look for the file "default.aspx" in the folder you are requesting in your URL. Try accessing it directly like this

```
https://server1.acme.com/folder/default.aspx
```

Your web servers "root" folder must contain a folder named "folder" in this example.

Port 443 is usually configured for SSL connections by default so your URL should start with https, as I have shown above, and you shouldn't have to specify the port in the URL.

Are you happy that your SSL configuration is correct?

Comment: It was a SSL configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

`404` means that page is not found. This is told by IIS server. so you can already connect it.